# How do you calculate for overflow in LC3 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, integer-overflow, lc3

I have written a program that find the LCM of two positive integers, but I need to account for overflow. The number can only be between `0 - x7FFF`. So how could I write the code so that it will see overflow and set `R3` to `-1` when overflow does occur?

Comment: That depends on the operation you expect the overflow from. For addition, a common check is to see whether the sum is less than one of the operands.

Comment: In general, addition and multiplication overflow can be anticipated by checking whether the max value possible when subtracted from / divided by the second operand is `>=` than the first operand.